# Points inside circular sector

Tags: algorithm, geolocation, geometry, orientation

I am working on a mobile application. My application gets the user position and orientation and then show some points of interest near his location.
Now, what I need is to know if the user is in front of a point of interest. My idea is to do this based on his position and orientation, using a circular sector of a small radius (about 5 meters) and I want to know if there is any formula or if anyone has a recommendation on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have Lat/Lon coordinates and user moving/viewing azimuth.
You can calculate direction to object and it's bearing (azimuth) and compare with your limits.

Note: It is difficult to ensure 5 meters precision with GPS/geolocation

This [excellent page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)  contains all the needed formulas. Excerpt:

```
distance
JavaScript: 
var R = 6371000; // metres
var φ1 = lat1.toRadians();
var φ2 = lat2.toRadians();
var Δφ = (lat2-lat1).toRadians();
var Δλ = (lon2-lon1).toRadians();

var a = Math.sin(Δφ/2) * Math.sin(Δφ/2) +
        Math.cos(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2) *
        Math.sin(Δλ/2) * Math.sin(Δλ/2);
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

var d = R * c;

bearing
JavaScript:
(all angles in radians)
var y = Math.sin(λ2-λ1) * Math.cos(φ2);
var x = Math.cos(φ1)*Math.sin(φ2) -
        Math.sin(φ1)*Math.cos(φ2)*Math.cos(λ2-λ1);
var brng = Math.atan2(y, x).toDegrees();
```